# How to set boolean field to false using a lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I'm trying to set a boolean field to False when a lightning component on the case object is clicked.

Component

```
<aura:component controller="UnescalateController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global" >
      <aura:at>tribute name="CaseObj" type="Case" default="{ 'sobjectType' : 'case'}"/>
      <lightning:button label="Unescalate" onclick="{! c.unescalate}"/>
</aura:component>
```

JS Controller

```
({
  unescalate : function(component, event, helper) {

      var caseObject = component.get("v.CaseObj");
        caseObject.Admin_Escalation__c = FALSE;


      var action = component.get("c.updateAdmin_Escalation__c");
          action.setParams({
            obj: caseObject,
            oId : component.get("v.recordId")  
        });
      // set call back 
        action.setCallback(this, function(response) {

            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert('This case has been unescalated!');
                $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();
            }
             else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
                alert("From server: " + response.getReturnValue());
            } else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " + errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        });
        // enqueue the action
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
   }
})
```

I'm pretty new to lightning components and have been playing around for a while. I'm specifically getting the following error : Uncaught Action failed: c:UnEscalate$controller$unescalate [FALSE is not defined]
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `caseObject.Admin_Escalation__c = false;` ?

Comment: Hi @MartinLezer I did indeed, I get "Uncaught Unable to find action 'Admin_Escalation__c' on the controller of c:UnEscalate" on updating it to : caseObject.Admin_Escalation__c = false;

Comment: Can you please post apex controller code as well?

Answer (score 1):

Javascript doesn't understand uppercase `FALSE` or `TRUE`. It should be in small case `false` and `true`.

Setting `caseObject.Admin_Escalation__c = false;` should work.

Comment: Yeah I did try that, however, still getting an error albeit slightly different ""Uncaught Unable to find action 'Admin_Escalation__c' on the controller of c:UnEscalate" on updating it to : caseObject.Admin_Escalation__c = false;"

Comment: Does the user has necessary permission of that field?

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working.

```
public class UnescalateCaseController {
@AuraEnabled
public static Case getCase(Id recordId){
    Case caseRec = [SELECT Id, Admin_Escalation__c FROM Case WHERE id=:recordId];
    return caseRec;
}

@AuraEnabled
public static Case saveCase(Case caseRec){

    caseRec.Admin_Escalation__c = FALSE;

    update caseRec;
    return caseRec;
}
```

}

```
<aura:component controller="UnescalateCaseController" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}"/>
<aura:attribute name="case" type="Case"/>
<ui:button aura:id="unescalatebtn" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" label="Unescalate" press="{!c.onclick}" disabled="{!v.case.Admin_Escalation__c == false ? 'true' : 'false'}"/>
```